# Disable User-Agent based Vary header response in nginx?

Tags: nginx, http, http-headers

It seems that nginx includes a `Vary: Accept-Encoding` header in some cases regardless of the file types I specify via "gzip_types".

I do not have much experience with nginx. Does it in fact send `Vary: Accept-Encoding` headers depending on the requesting `User-Agent` header?

Also, is there a setting (or combination of settings) that can be modified in order to stop nginx from sending `Vary: Accept-Encoding` headers for specific User-Agents?

There seem to be quite a few settings and I simply do not know which take precedence.

I suppose something like the following would not achieve what I want (I still want the `Vary: Accept-Encoding` response for *file types* **only**):
gzip_disable "*";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you'd want to change this. `Vary:` tells any caching proxy that it can not rely purely on the URL to cache the result and that it also needs to take into account of the `Accept-Encoding:` header too. This is the correct behaviour. You are going to get a different response if your client says it can deal with compressed responses or not. Without this header, a cache may attempt to send a compressed response to a client that can't handle it.

Comment: I do understand the Vary header's function and that of Accept-Encoding, however, I am trying to work around a bug and for the time being I need to be able to send the `Vary:Accept-Encoding` header only for certain file types and can re-implement the `User-Agent` functionality at a later date -- but I don't know how to disable it in the first place.